# Building a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio. And I have 2 queries, that I need to merge into one.

First one is (you do not need to get the meaning of it, just skip to the next text):

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.project.name AS Project_name, Test_Run.documentKey AS TestRun_Key, Test_Run.entitytype, Test_Run.documentKey, 
                  Test_Case.documentKey AS TestCase_Key, document_1.name AS TestPlan_Name, dbo.lookup.name AS TestCase_Release_Status, 
                  Test_Run.testRunStatus AS TestRun_Status, Test_Run.active, dbo.project.id AS Project_ID, dbo.version.versionNumber, Test_Run.executionDate AS Execution_Date, 
                  Test_Run.globalId AS TR_glID, Test_Case.globalId AS TC_glID, Test_Run.createdDate AS TR_Created_Date, Test_Case.id AS TestCase_ID, 
                  Test_Run.id AS TestRun_ID
FROM         dbo.[document] AS Test_Run INNER JOIN
                  dbo.project ON Test_Run.projectId = dbo.project.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] AS Test_Case ON Test_Run.testCaseId = Test_Case.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.testrunset ON Test_Run.testRunSetId = dbo.testrunset.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] ON dbo.testrunset.testCycleId = dbo.[document].id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] AS document_1 ON dbo.[document].testPlanId = document_1.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.version ON Test_Run.testCaseVersionNumber = dbo.version.versionNumber AND Test_Run.testCaseId = dbo.version.originDocumentId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue ON dbo.version.documentId = dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.documentId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.lookup ON dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.textValue = dbo.lookup.id
WHERE     (Test_Run.documentTypeId = 55) AND (dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.fieldId = 216) AND (Test_Run.active = N'T') AND (Test_Case.testCaseStatusId <> 2)
```

ORDER BY TestCase_Key
And I have saved this query as a view **MyView** and using it in the following query:

```
select TestCase_Key, TestRun_Status, Project_Name

from (select TestCase_Key, TestRun_Status, Project_Name,
         row_number() over(partition by TestCase_Key order by Execution_Date desc) as rn
  from MyView) as T

where rn = 1 and (Project_Name = 'TestProject')
    ORDER BY TestRun_Status, TestCase_Key
```

Now I need to merge these 2 queries, i.e. I am not allowed to use a view in my use case. Could someone help or give a hint? I have experimented whith "in" clause, but did not succeed.

Comment: Since your second query is just looking for 1 row only, change your first query to select top 1. And add in the extra constraints into the where, and adjust the order by

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for hints. Its plausible and Ive tried it, but it didn't work by me. Could you tell, where I should put this   **row_number() over(partition by TestCase_Key order by Execution_Date desc) as rn** to make it work?

Comment: Just to check that we are going in the same direction, can you say in plain English what you are trying to return with the second query? It looks like you want rn=1 so that is the first row only from the view, but you have sorting in the view that is then overridden by the order by in the row_number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the latest Execution date for each TestCase_Key, I have revised my original answer.

I have used your original view as a derived table and removed the order by and top 100% that were required for the unnecessary sorting.

```
select TestCase_Key, TestRun_Status, Project_Name

from (select TestCase_Key, TestRun_Status, Project_Name,
         row_number() over(partition by TestCase_Key order by Execution_Date desc) as rn
  from 
  (SELECT    dbo.project.name AS Project_name, Test_Run.documentKey AS TestRun_Key, Test_Run.entitytype, Test_Run.documentKey, 
                  Test_Case.documentKey AS TestCase_Key, document_1.name AS TestPlan_Name, dbo.lookup.name AS TestCase_Release_Status, 
                  Test_Run.testRunStatus AS TestRun_Status, Test_Run.active, dbo.project.id AS Project_ID, dbo.version.versionNumber, Test_Run.executionDate AS Execution_Date, 
                  Test_Run.globalId AS TR_glID, Test_Case.globalId AS TC_glID, Test_Run.createdDate AS TR_Created_Date, Test_Case.id AS TestCase_ID, 
                  Test_Run.id AS TestRun_ID
FROM         dbo.[document] AS Test_Run INNER JOIN
                  dbo.project ON Test_Run.projectId = dbo.project.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] AS Test_Case ON Test_Run.testCaseId = Test_Case.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.testrunset ON Test_Run.testRunSetId = dbo.testrunset.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] ON dbo.testrunset.testCycleId = dbo.[document].id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.[document] AS document_1 ON dbo.[document].testPlanId = document_1.id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.version ON Test_Run.testCaseVersionNumber = dbo.version.versionNumber AND Test_Run.testCaseId = dbo.version.originDocumentId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue ON dbo.version.documentId = dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.documentId INNER JOIN
                  dbo.lookup ON dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.textValue = dbo.lookup.id
WHERE     (Test_Run.documentTypeId = 55) AND (dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.fieldId = 216) AND (Test_Run.active = N'T') AND (Test_Case.testCaseStatusId <> 2)) 
 as DerivedTable) as T

where rn = 1 and (Project_Name = 'TestProject')
    ORDER BY TestRun_Status, TestCase_Key
```

If that is what you need, then you can flatten it by removing one of the layers, and removing extra columns and tables that are not required for the final result

Here it is flattened, hopefully you will be able to remove some joins in the inner select statement:

```
    SELECT TestCase_Key
    , TestRun_Status
    , Project_Name
FROM
    (
    SELECT dbo.project.name AS Project_name
        , Test_Case.documentKey AS TestCase_Key
        , Test_Run.testRunStatus AS TestRun_Status
        , Test_Run.executionDate AS Execution_Date
    FROM dbo.[document] AS Test_Run
        INNER JOIN dbo.project ON Test_Run.projectId = dbo.project.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.[document] AS Test_Case ON Test_Run.testCaseId = Test_Case.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.testrunset ON Test_Run.testRunSetId = dbo.testrunset.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.[document] ON dbo.testrunset.testCycleId = dbo.[document].id
    INNER JOIN dbo.[document] AS document_1 ON dbo.[document].testPlanId = document_1.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.version ON Test_Run.testCaseVersionNumber = dbo.version.versionNumber
                         AND Test_Run.testCaseId = dbo.version.originDocumentId
    INNER JOIN dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue ON dbo.version.documentId = dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.documentId
    INNER JOIN dbo.lookup ON dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.textValue = dbo.lookup.id
    WHERE(Test_Run.documentTypeId = 55)
        AND (dbo.documentcustomfieldvalue.fieldId = 216)
        AND (Test_Run.active = N'T')
        AND (Test_Case.testCaseStatusId <> 2)
    ) AS DerivedTable
WHERE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TestCase_Key ORDER BY Execution_Date DESC) = 1
     AND (Project_Name = 'TestProject')
ORDER BY TestRun_Status
      , TestCase_Key;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, after your comment, I realized I put a wrong query in the first one now its a right one there. I am not getting a proper result with only using select top(1)  what criteria does it use to choose the entry it shows? In my use case I have test cases, each has a respective test run status, to this test run status belongs an execution date. I need only to show the entries with the latest execution date for each test run status.

Comment: I see now that you want the row 1 for each TestCase_Key based on the latest Test_Run.executionDate. I will redo the query. but essentially if you take the first query, strip out the order by and top 100%, wrap it in brackets and insert that code in front of MyView in your current query it should work, then can clean it up

Comment: hmm.. that was actually the first thing that I tried, but it didn't work.. However I had 100 percent there and now I tried again without it and it still didn't work..

Comment: Have you tried the 2 versions of the query that are in my revised answer

Comment: I will check it now

Comment: Even though the second one does not work, smth with formatting there, but the first one is working! Ive tried this simple nesting before but with 100 procent thing and it didn't work, so I thought it cannot be done this way.. Awesome, thanks a lot!! I will manage to shorten it down on my own..